# Finite composition factors

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group with a composition series

$G=G_0>G_1>\cdots>G_n=1$

Let $H_i=G_i/G_{i+1}$ the composition factors.

I want to prove that if each $H_i$ is finite then $G$ must be finite.

In fact, I read that it is $|G|=\prod|H_i|$ (of course I'm only interested in the fact that $G$ must be finite).

I don't know if this is easy, but I can't prove it yet. Would you give my any hint?

Thanks.

Comment: *Hint:*  induction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quotient group $G_i/G_{i+1}$ is the group of cosets of $G_{i+1}$ within $G_i$.  Remember that

- Every coset of $G_{i+1}$ has just as many elements as $G_{i+1}$ itself has; and
- No two distinct cosets intersect each other; and
- Every element of $G_i$ is a member of some coset.

In other words, one is partitioning $G_i$ into disjoint subsets all of the same size that fill up all of $G_i$.  So for example if every coset has $12$ members and there are $10$ cosets, then $G_i$ has $10\times12=120$ members.  In other words $|G_i|/|G_{i+1}|=|G_i/G_{i+1}|$.  Or one can say
$$
|G_i| = |G_i/G_{i+1}|\cdot|G_{i+1}|.
$$
So you're just multiplying finite numbers to get the size of each larger group in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that $|G|=|G/H|\cdot|H|$? Use it inductively.